# How to prove this greedy algorithm as optimal?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

The problem sounds like this: we get n-cubes. Each cube has a length (the edge's length) and a colour. The edges' lengths are distinct, but the culours are not, for instance: any two cubes can never have the same length, but it is possible to have the same colour. The colours are from 1 to p (p is given).

We have to build a cube-tower that has a maximum height, following these rules:

1) a cube cannot be placed upon a cube if they have the same colour;

2) a cube cannot pe placed upon a cube whose edge's length is smaller.

e.g: cube c1 has a length of 3, cube c2 has a length of 5. cube c1 can be placed on the top of c2, but cube c2 cannot be placed on the top of c1.

Alright, so the algorithm I came up with in order to solve this problem is this:

1. we sort the cubes by edge length, in descending order and we put them in an array;
2. we add the first cube in the array to the Tower;
3. we save the length of the last inserted cube( in this case, the first cube's length ) in variable l;
4. we save the colour of the last inserted cube( in this case, the first cube's colour ) in variable c;
5. we go through the rest of the array, inserting the first cube whose length is smaller than l and colour different than c and then we repeat 3-4-5;

Now what I'm having difficulties with is, how do I prove this greedy algorithm to be the optimal one? I guess that the proof has to somehow look like the ones here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/04GreedyAlgorithmsI-2x2.pdf

Comment: @trincot cubes cannot have the same lengths, I mentioned it when i explained the problem: "any two cubes can never have the same length"

Comment: Ah, right. missed that. So the test *"whose length is smaller than l "* in step 5 is really not necessary as that will always be the case for all subsequent cubes.

Comment: @ trincot True, true, I wrote that just for it being more clear, I guess.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66057/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is:

- *Is there a case where picking the max-length cube is not optimal?*

At each decision-node we have to decide if we pick **a** or **b**, given **a>b**:

**Assume picking b is strictly optimal (implies max-height)**:

- **Case 1:** `col(a) == col(b)`
- `b optimal => final tower: b, x0, x1, ...`
- but also valid by construction with equal height: `a, x0, x1, ...`
- valid because: `col(a) == col(b)`, `(a > b) & (b > x0) => (a > x0)` (transitivity)
- contradiction!
- **Case 2** `col(a) != col(b)`
- `b optimal -> final tower: b, x0, x1, ...`
- but also valid construction with more height: `a, b, x0, x1, ...`
- valid because: `(a > b) & (col(a) != col(b)) => a before b`
- contradiction!

We assumed picking b is strictly optimal and showed contradictions. Picking b can only be equally good or worse than picking a (the max-length cube of the remaining ones).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I find this to be kind of confusing, what do you mean by "col", colour? and who is a or b? the lengths? and who are x0, x1... ?

Comment: @VasileTurcu Yes, col = color; a and b are the next cubes to choose where we call the bigger candidate a, the smaller one b. x0, x1, ... are all the other cubes, already stacked in some solution, where x0 > x1 > x2, ...

Comment: well then, shouldn't the question be "Is there a case where picking the max cube is not optimal?"